# Differenze di uso tra "riflettuto" e "riflesso"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs, difference, past-participle

Il [participio passato del verbo "riflettere"](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx?v=riflettere) può essere sia "riflettuto" che "riflesso". Ci sono differenze di uso tra questi due vocaboli? Potreste spiegarmele?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Io userei la forma "riflettuto" per riflettere nel significato di pensare, mentre "riflesso" per riflettere nel significato di specchiarsi, di un raggio di sole riflesso sul lago e via dicendo.

[Una breve ricerca online](http://www.linkuaggio.com/2011/11/riflesso-o-riflettuto-la-forma-corretta.html) aiuta a confermare la mia impressione.

Anche l'[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/verbi-difficili) scrive qualcosa a riguardo.

Comment: Il dizionario Treccani [concorda](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riflettere/).